# Modify url for bookmarking using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ajax, javascript-framework

I'm exploring my options for modifying urls in the browser bar for bookmarking purposes.

Ideally, I'd like to add querystring parameters and cannot determine if this is even possible.  I don't want the page to refresh and want to add querystring values on link clicks, ajax calls, etc.

If I can't add querystring parameters, then I'd like to add hash values (http:://someurl.com#hash-value).  How should I go about doing this?  Should I use plain JavaScript or a framework (jquery, prototype, etc.) and/or framework plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To modify the hash, you can simply do the following in plain JavaScript:

```
window.location.hash = 'hash-value';
```

It will add `#hash-value` to your URL, or will replace it if it already exists, without refreshing the page.

Then to check if a hash value is present, simply do the following:

```
if (window.location.hash) {
    // Hash is present
    // Use window.location.hash as required
}
else {
    // No hash was set
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you modify the query string, it will refresh.  So you should modify window.location.hash.